# aws graphql appsync api integration with aws connect chat

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync, appsync-subscription

I am trying to create support chat service in my flutter app and I have used appsync api for functions , so I want use appsync api for chat between user and aws connect chat agent , so is there any way to integrate this using lambda?
so that agent can send message and the user from different app can see the message as it is subscribed to the mutation?  If yes how can achieve it?
I am seeing we can use aws sns , but it's not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.